# Django: How can I get hashtags from string when post_save of an object?

Tags: django

Let's say I have a class Post and it has caption and tags fields.

In the post_save signal, I want to find hashtags in the captions and save to tags field comma-seperated. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for this

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'some #example #post caption'
>>> m = re.findall('(?:#([^\s]+))+', s)
>>> m
['example', 'post']
>>> ', '.join(m)
'example, post'
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid recursion you'll have to disconnect and reconnect your signal handler so you can save your instance.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from myapp.models import Post

def parse_hash_tags(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    post_save.disconnect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)
    instance.tags = ','.join(re.findall(r'(?:#(\w+))', instance.caption))
    instance.save()
    post_save.connect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)

post_save.connect(parse_hash_tags, sender=Post)
```